# PetaPoco transaction isolation level

Tags: c#, sql-server, petapoco

I have a c# windows service which updates data in my database using [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), all wrapped into a transaction. However, I need the database to be available for queries while the transaction runs (web app, running queries through an ODBC connection), but if queried while the transaction is being committed, I get a "Catastrophic failure" error from my database. Currently testing against MS SQL Server, but also need this working against Oracle databases.

Is there any way to set the transaction isolation level for PetaPoco transactions, and could this be the solution in this case?

Comment: How did you forced PetaPoco to use ODBC???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the "Catastrophic failure" messages originated from deadlocks in the database caused by updates from both PetaPoco and my existing web app. I resolved this by locking the tables with

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [TABLENAME] WITH (TABLOCKX)
```

queries at the start of the PetaPoco transaction.